# How to diagnose why a VS project is being rebuilt

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, build

I currently have a VB.NET project that always gets rebuilt even though I made no changes to it and I'm trying to find why.

I came across this page https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/main/docs/repo/up-to-date-check-implementation.md explaining the up-to-date check implementation, which is great but I don't fully understand all of the checks at a level that I can actually look at my project and find what's causing the rebuild.

Is there a diagnostics tool or more detailed description or even a practical way of running the attached source code of the steps to help diagnosing why a particular project is not skipped?

Answer (score 0):

In "Tools->Options", go to "Projects and Solutions->Compile and execute". There you have two dropdown boxes to change the verbosity of the build output. If you increase them, the build will output a reason for each project on why it or parts of it where rebuilt. A setting of "Normal" should be enough, otherwise you easily get to much information.